# How to add a "next" button to the sliderInput of R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I plot GPS data on a leaflet map using R,
the trip is visualised through an incrementing timeline provided by the sliderInput in animation mode.

```
 sliderInput("animation", "Mesures GPS :",
                                  min = ifelse( !exists("i.data"), 0, min(i.data$sequence)),
                                  max = ifelse( !exists("i.data"), 1, max(i.data$sequence)),
                                  value = 0,
                                  step=20,
                                  animate = animationOptions(interval = 1000, loop = FALSE),
                                  width="100%"))
```

I can see the GPS points jumping over the map, and now I am looking for the way to have a "next" button ([<<], [>>]) to control more finely local steps. I have not seen any such option in the sliderInput documentation.

This could also be done by adding ad-hoc shiny actionButtons,

any suggestion?

Comment: Yup, add ad-hoc `shiny::actionButton`s.

Comment: ... then `observeEvent` those button presses and `updateSliderInput(session, inputId, value = ...)`.

Comment: I follow your advice, adding just << >> made nice 5min job buttons!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting the code from `?sliderInput`:

```r
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:center;",
          actionButton("left", label = "<<")),
      div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:center;",
          sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                      min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
                      )),
      div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:center;",
          actionButton("right", label = ">>")),
    ),
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  ),
  # Server logic
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(input$obs))
    })
    observeEvent(input$left, {
      updateSliderInput(session, "obs", value = input$obs - 10)
    })
    observeEvent(input$right, {
      updateSliderInput(session, "obs", value = input$obs + 10)
    })
  }
)
```

[image: shiny app]

This updates by +/- 10.

Comment: This solution is fine, but I would replace label = "<<" by label="", icon("angle-double-up", "fa-1x") for a prettier rendering.

Comment: Sure, I was focusing on the mechanics over aesthetics (though I did add the inline part).